# Detect position scroll of draggableScrollableSheet and override widget other?

Tags: flutter, scroll

I use DraggableScrollableSheet and contain tabview inside.

My target is that when scrolling, DraggableScrollableSheet will override the top tabview.
Here's what I want:
https://media.giphy.com/media/151brg1VCvrTTMPheB/giphy.gif

Are there any libraries that support this?
Do I have to listen for scrroll events?

myCode:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class CustomScreenTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomScreenState createState() => _CustomScreenState();
}

class _CustomScreenState extends State<CustomScreenTest2> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('111'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: DefaultTabController(
              length: 3,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    height: 70,
                    child: TabBar(
                      tabs: <Tab>[
                        new Tab(
                          text: "1",
                          icon: new Icon(Icons.show_chart),
                        ),
                        new Tab(
                          text: "2",
                          icon: new Icon(Icons.history),
                        ),
                        new Tab(
                          text: "3",
                          icon: new Icon(Icons.terrain),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    height: 500,
                    child: TabBarView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Center(
                          child: Text('1'),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text('2'),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Text('2'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          _buildBody()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              minChildSize: 0.03,
              maxChildSize: 0.9,
              builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) => SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                child: DefaultTabController(
                  initialIndex: 0,
                  length: 4,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 10,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.amber,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            height: 5,
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        child: TabBar(tabs: <Widget>[
                          Tab(
                              child: Text(
                            '4',
                          )),
                          Tab(
                              child: Text(
                            '5',
                          )),
                          Tab(
                              child: Text(
                            '6',
                          )),
                          Tab(
                              child: Text(
                            '7',
                          )),
                        ]),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: TabBarView(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('4'),
                            Text('5'),
                            Text('6'),
                            Text('7'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you get the answer?

Comment: @NightNinja i had , customize https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel . Thank for your attention.